# Dymos: How to call solve_ivp method explicitly for solving Dynamics Equations?

Tags: scipy, openmdao

I am trying to setup a trajectory optimization problem in Dymos.

For the validation of the analysis model to be used, I wish to calculate trajectory for some initial conditions.

I have tried solve_segments=True method as mentioned [here](https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/getting_started/intro_to_dymos/intro_ivp.html), however it is capable of calculating trajectories for only small values of time_duration (~20 seconds). After doing some experiments I figured out that no matter what num_segments value I choose, the trajectory shows a sudden overshoot near the end-values of times.

For example:
a) `num_segments=15, order=3`, `t_duration=25`
[image]
with a random error: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

b) However, when I set `num_segents=15, order=3`, `t_duration=20`
[image]
This trajectory definitely seems correct! The transcription was GaussLobatto in both the cases.

Since the equations of dynamics are a bit too complicated, I would like to know if there's any other way to just solve the equations.

Is there any way to call scipy's solve_ivp method on the case that is already setup (`prob.setup()`)? i.e.to call `trajectory.simulate()` without calling `problem.run_model()`?

**My other question is:**
I am thinking to try a dummy objective style to solve the equations. Can anyone please guide on the same? We haven't formed our objectives for this problem yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't necessarily have a solution for you, but I have a few suggestions.

Unfortunately, simulate() relies on some outputs being populated, and the only way to do that is to execute the model (with `run_model()` or `run_driver()`)

If you use `dymos.run_problem(p, simulate=True)` to run the first 20 second problem, that should generate two recorded files.  `dymos_solution.db` will contain the implicit solution, and `dymos_simulation.db` will contain the simulated solution.  You can see a subsequent solution with these files by doing something like:

```
dm.run_problem(prob, simulate=True, restart='dymos_solution.db')
```

Have you tried bounding your states?  If so, the Radau method may work better, since theres no interpolation step as there is in GaussLobatto.

Have you run `prob.check_partials(compact_print=True)` to verify that your derivatives are correct?